# RegDBKeyExists always returns -1 (incorrectly)

Tags: windows, installation, installshield

I want to look for a registry but it always returns -1 (don't exist), even when actually it exists.

Please see my code and see if I'm missing something:

```
export prototype installFramework(HWND);

function installFramework(hMSI)
  STRING szProgram, szKey, szName, szValue, szMsg;
  NUMBER reg, nSize, nResult;
begin        

REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTIONS | REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY;  
RegDBSetDefaultRoot(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);         

reg = RegDBKeyExist("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full\\Install");                               

if (reg < 0) then

  szMsg = "Message here.";

  MessageBox (szMsg, INFORMATION);   

  szProgram = INSTALLDIR ^ "dotnetfx40_full_x86_x64.exe";  
  LaunchAppAndWait(szProgram, "", WAIT );
endif; 
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're checking if `key exists` then you have to do this:

```
   reg = RegDBKeyExist("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full");
```

`RegDBKeyexist will only check if a key exists, not a value.` from [flexerasoftware.com](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=93666)

To check for `To find out if a value exists then you can use the RegDBGetKeyValueEx function and check if it fails to get the value.`

you were checking for `RegDBKeyExist("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full\\Install");`
where `Install` is a value, so it was giving you `-1`

Comment: This was exactly the problem! Thank you!